# Facebook API - Get inbox messages count

Tags: facebook-graph-api

My Facebook app should show me the friend with whom i have the largest amount of inbox messages. I got all inbox threads and I can get each message in threads, but app uses many API calls so it may get a 'Too Many Calls' error. Is there a way to get only messages count in a thread object?

Please, don't recommend FQL because it's deprecated in current Facebook API version (v2.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to get a count of the inbox messages, you may try to include a limit parameter to get more comments in one call. But the main point is that you need the `read_mailbox` permission for this and you will most likely not get it approved:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_mailbox